# error while catkin_make in catkin_ws

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**The specified base path "/home/user/catkin_ws" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace**
i have followed step by step given in tutorial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250089/error-while-catkin_make-in-catkin_ws/) by [abhay2302](https://answers.ros.org/users/28289/abhay2302/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/221538/the-specified-base-path-homeruicatkin_ws-contains-a-package-but-catkin_make-must-be-invoked-in-the-root-of-workspace-how-can-i-fix-it/?answer=221553#post-id-221553).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0